# How does Hadoop/MapReduce scale when input data is NOT stored?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

The intended use for Hadoop appears to be for when the input data is [distributed](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module1.html#data) (HDFS) and already stored local to the nodes at the time of the mapping process.

Suppose we have data which does not need to be stored; the data can be generated at runtime. For example, the input to the mapping process is to be every possible IP address. Is Hadoop capable of efficiently distributing the Mapper work across nodes? Would you need to explicitly define how to split the input data (i.e. the IP address space) to different nodes, or does Hadoop handle that automatically?

Comment: How do you plan to feed it the data? "suppose it isn't stored" implies you'd have to write an `InputFormat`, if you think of generating a file containing all possible IPs, HDFS will split it into chunks for you anyway. You're forced to split it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me first clarify a comment you made.  Hadoop is designed to support potentially massively parallel computation across a potentially large number of nodes regardless of where the data comes from or goes.  The Hadoop design favors scalability over performance when it has to.  It is true that being clever about where the data starts out and how that data is distributed can make a significant difference in how well/quickly a hadoop job can run.

To your question and example, if you will generate the input data you have the choice of generating it before the first job runs or you can generate it within the first mapper.  If you generate it within the mapper then you can figure out what node the mapper's running on and then generate just the data that would be reduced in that partition (Use a partitioner to direct data between mappers and reducers)

This is going to be a problem you'll have with any distributed platform. Storm, for example, lets you have some say in which bolt instance will will process each tuple.  The terminology might be different, but you'll be implementing roughly the same shuffle algorithm in Storm as you would Hadoop.

Comment: Assuming you meant [Storm](http://storm-project.net/), (luckily) it's not under Apache.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to run a non-MapReduce task on a map reduce cluster then. (e.g. IP scanning?) There may be more appropriate tools for this, your know...

A thing few people do not realize is that MapReduce is about *checkpointing*. It was developed for huge clusters, where you can expect machines to fail during the computation. By having checkpointing and recovery built-in into the architecture, this reduces the consequences of failures and slow hosts.

And that is why everything goes from disk to disk in MapReduce. It's checkpointed before, and it's checkpointed after. And if it fails, only this part of the job is re-run.

You can easily outperform MapReduce by leaving away the checkpointing. If you have 10 nodes, you will win easily. If you have 100 nodes, you will usually win. If you have a major computation and 1000 nodes, chances are that one node fails and you wish you had been doing similar checkpointing...

Now your task doesn't sound like a MapReduce job, because the input data is virtual. It sounds much more as if you should be running some other distributed computing tool; and maybe just writing your initial result to HDFS for *later* processing via MapReduce.

But of course there are way to hack around this. For example, you could use /16 subnets as input. Each mapper reads a /16 subnet and does it's job on that. It's not that much fake input to generate if you realize that you don't need to generate all 2^32 IPs, unless you have that many nodes in your cluster...

Answer (score 1):

Number of Mappers depends on the number of Splits generated by the implementation of the InputFormat. 
There is [NLineInputFormat](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop-0.20.2-CDH3B4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html), which you could configure to generate as many splits as there are lines in the input file. You could create a file where each line is an IP range. I have not used it personally and there are many reports that it does not work as expected. 
If you really need it, you could create your own implementation of the InputFormat which generates the InputSplits for your virtual data and force as many mappers as you need.